# Stamen Map Toner substr error Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, stamen-maps

I've been using this Toner Map by Stamen for a while. I built it using Google Maps. Its been working on multiple sites for the last 5-6 months.

I just checked today as a client complained and they are all broken.

Stamen: 
http://maps.stamen.com/#watercolor/12/37.7706/-122.3782

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'substr'
```

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hnuTt/12/

Javascript:

```
var layer = 'toner';
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.514635,-0.092992),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: layer,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [layer]
    }
});
map.mapTypes.set(layer, new google.maps.StamenMapType(layer));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.499405,-0.390596),
    map: map
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem on multiple sites as well...

Comment: Its very annoying. I think it has something to do with a update from Google and not stamen. I'd be interested to know what though. Feel free to spread this question, maybe someone will answer.

Comment: Yeah stamens maps are up on their site. Does your sites have anything more in common? All three i have trouble with is on WordPress

Comment: The ones on their site are using their Map API and not Google Maps API. All of my sites that are broken are using wordpress as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem with stamen and other tile providers.

Since yesterday, default Google Maps API loaded (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false) seems to be version **3.13**, which isnt the release version and might contains bugs.

In emergency the solution is to load **3.12** version which is the release version :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.12&sensor=false

I haven't tried yet to find a working solution with **3.13**